# Retrieve available sheet formats of specific printer

Tags: c++, windows, printing

As I written in the title, I was looking for a way to retrieve available sheets format of a specific printer in C++. At the moment I can only retrieve the current settings in this way:

```
LPWSTR pName = L"My Printer Name";
HANDLE _printerHandle;
OpenPrinterW(pName, &_printerHandle, NULL);

LONG size = DocumentPropertiesW(NULL, _printerHandle, pName, NULL, NULL, 0);
PDEVMODEW info = (PDEVMODEW)malloc(size); //here I get/set settings
DocumentPropertiesW(NULL, _printerHandle, pName, info, NULL, DM_OUT_BUFFER);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Printing/PrinterSettings.cs,4ad9eb15ffdeec05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DeviceCapabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552(v=vs.85).aspx) to query for `DC_BINS`.  That'll give you an array of WORDs, where each word corresponds to a paper source.  (Look at the description of the `dmDefaultSource` in the description of the `DEVMODE` to interpret the values.)

You can also use DeviceCapabilities to query for `DC_PAPERS` or `DC_PAPERSIZES` to learn about supported paper sizes.

Comment: I tried to query for DC_PAPERS but I cannot figured out how to get values. Here's a piece of code I tried to execute: 
`DWORD deviceCapabilitiesSize = DeviceCapabilitiesW(info->pPrinterName, info->pPortName, DC_PAPERS, NULL, currentSettings); LPWSTR bins = (LPWSTR)malloc(deviceCapabilitiesSize + 1); DeviceCapabilitiesW(info->pPrinterName, info->pPortName, DC_PAPERS, bins, currentSettings); std::wcout << L"Available bins: " << std::endl; std::wcout << bins << std::endl;` where info is a `PRINTER_INFO_2W` structure